# Is possible remove a event listener without removeEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There´s my problem. I have this div with the event onclick():

```
<div style="float: left; margin-bottom: 10px; background-image: url('../bundles/web/img/370799.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; margin-left: 5px; border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: -10px;">
    {% for card in cards %}
       <div id="{{ card.id }}" onclick="getImage({{ card.id }})" style="float:left;">
            <img class="img-responsive" style="width: 100px; height: 130px;"  src="{{'../bundles/web/img/cartas/' ~ card.image }}">
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And this javascript for remove the Event Listener, but i read the documentation of removeEventListener() but says that this function only works with the use of addEventListener():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function getImage(e) {
      document.getElementById(1).appendChild(
          document.getElementById(e)
      );

      document.getElementById(e).removeEventListener("onclick", getImage);
   }
</script>
```

That´s all. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove an inline event handler by setting the respective property value to null

```
document.getElementById(e).onclick = null;
```

Comment: ... or undefined or empty string or anything :-)

Comment: @devnull69 An [event handler](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers) can either have the value null, or be set to a callback object, or be set to an internal raw uncompiled handler. So I think `null` is better, even if other values also work because they are converted to null under the hood.